# Python 3.4.2 compile py to exe with images and sounds

Tags: python, compilation, exe, py2exe

I have my python script (battleships.py) and also along with them I have a couple of images and a few wav sound files.

How can I compile it all into one exe file setup so it installs on the users pc and they can then run it with a shortcut, let's say from the desktop.

I've looked around at py2exe and cx_freeze but I can't seem to get them to work.

I'm using python 3.4.2

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no other choice than `py2exe` or `cx_freeze`.
But I think only cx_freeze works in Python3. You should install it manually. After downloading it and having unzipped it you may run:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

(you can do this in a *virtualenv*)

### EDIT:

It seems that it is no more necessary to install it manually for Python3.
You can get directly a Windows installer for Python3.4 version [there](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=cx_Freeze&version=4.3.3).

Comment: How do i compile it after installing it?

Comment: Ok, i've installed it but now what? Do I have to move my script to somewhere or something how do I actually convert it? Thanks :)

Comment: I think now you should read the man (docs). I don't remember how to use it !